# Problems with creating windows installer for panda3d application using pdeploy

Tags: python, panda3d

Some time ago I've wrote my first game using Panda3d game engine and now I wish to share it with my friends. Actually, I know how to do it: I've generated .p3d multifile and run

```
pdeploy -s -N "Cobra" -v 0.2 cobra.p3d installer
```

in my shell. I recieved this warning:

```
:Installer(warning): Makensis utility not found, no Windows installer will be built!
```

How to fix it? `apt-get install makensis` doesn't help.

**UPD:**

I am using **Ubuntu 12.04** and Panda 1.8.1. So, if one line of output can nothing to say, there is whole log:

```
$ pdeploy -s -N "Cobra" -v 0.2 cobra.p3d installer
:AppRunner: Total Panda3D disk space used: 169 MB
:AppRunner: Configured max usage is: 2048 MB
:HostInfo: Downloading contents file [ https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093056 ]

:downloader: [0x9fd41a8] begin GET [ https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093056 ]
:HostInfo(warning): Successfully downloaded https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093056
Using author "Alexander Nefedov" <canadien@vancouver> with ID org.panda3d
:Installer(warning): Makensis utility not found, no Windows installer will be built!
:Installer: Creating .//linux_i386/cobra_0.2_i386.deb...
:PackageInfo: p3dembed downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/linux_i386/p3dembed.linux_i386.xml
:downloader: [0x9fe4cc0] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/linux_i386/p3dembed.linux_i386.xml ]
:PackageInfo: p3dembed downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/linux_i386/p3dembed.linux_i386.mf.1.pz
:downloader: [0x9fd5868] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/linux_i386/p3dembed.linux_i386.mf.1.pz ]
:PackageInfo: Uncompressing /tmp/cobraLFFwea/p3dembed/linux_i386/p3dembed.linux_i386.mf.1.pz to /tmp/cobraLFFwea/p3dembed/linux_i386/p3dembed.linux_i386.mf
:PackageInfo: Unpacking /tmp/cobraLFFwea/p3dembed/linux_i386/p3dembed.linux_i386.mf
:Standalone: Creating /tmp/cobralgZXTK/linux_i386/usr/bin/cobra...
:HostInfo: Downloading contents file [ https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093066 ]

:downloader: [0x9fd6740] begin GET [ https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093066 ]
:HostInfo(warning): Successfully downloaded https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093066
:PackageInfo: images downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.xml
:downloader: [0xa031498] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.xml ]
:PackageInfo: images downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.mf.1.pz
:downloader: [0xa031498] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.mf.1.pz ]
:PackageInfo: Uncompressing /tmp/cobralgZXTK/linux_i386/usr/lib/cobra/images/images.mf.1.pz to /tmp/cobralgZXTK/linux_i386/usr/lib/cobra/images/images.mf
:PackageInfo: Unpacking /tmp/cobralgZXTK/linux_i386/usr/lib/cobra/images/images.mf
:PackageInfo: panda3d downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/linux_i386/panda3d.cmu_1.8.linux_i386.xml
:downloader: [0x9fd6740] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/linux_i386/panda3d.cmu_1.8.linux_i386.xml ]
:PackageInfo: panda3d downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/linux_i386/panda3d.cmu_1.8.linux_i386.mf.1.pz
:downloader: [0xa04b838] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/linux_i386/panda3d.cmu_1.8.linux_i386.mf.1.pz ]
:PackageInfo: Uncompressing /tmp/cobralgZXTK/linux_i386/usr/lib/cobra/panda3d/cmu_1.8/panda3d.cmu_1.8.linux_i386.mf.1.pz to /tmp/cobralgZXTK/linux_i386/usr/lib/cobra/panda3d/cmu_1.8/panda3d.cmu_1.8.linux_i386.mf
:PackageInfo: Unpacking /tmp/cobralgZXTK/linux_i386/usr/lib/cobra/panda3d/cmu_1.8/panda3d.cmu_1.8.linux_i386.mf
:Installer: Creating .//linux_i386/cobra-0.2-1-i686.pkg.tar.gz...
:Installer: Creating .//osx_i386/Cobra.app...
:PackageInfo: p3dembed downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/osx_i386/p3dembed.osx_i386.xml
:downloader: [0xa1d5c80] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/osx_i386/p3dembed.osx_i386.xml ]
:PackageInfo: p3dembed downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/osx_i386/p3dembed.osx_i386.mf.1.pz
:downloader: [0xa02c490] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/osx_i386/p3dembed.osx_i386.mf.1.pz ]
:PackageInfo: Uncompressing /tmp/cobraLFFwea/p3dembed/osx_i386/p3dembed.osx_i386.mf.1.pz to /tmp/cobraLFFwea/p3dembed/osx_i386/p3dembed.osx_i386.mf
:PackageInfo: Unpacking /tmp/cobraLFFwea/p3dembed/osx_i386/p3dembed.osx_i386.mf
:Standalone: Creating .//osx_i386/Cobra.app/Contents/MacOS/cobra...
:PackageInfo: images downloading https://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.xml
:downloader: [0xa0be448] begin GET [ https://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.xml ]
:PackageInfo(warning): After downloading, images.xml incorrect
:HostInfo: Redownloading https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml
:HostInfo: Downloading contents file [ https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093206 ]

:downloader: [0xa153be0] begin GET [ https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093206 ]
:HostInfo(warning): Successfully downloaded https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093206
:HostInfo: https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml has changed.
:PackageInfo: images downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.xml
:downloader: [0xa091ef0] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.xml ]
:PackageInfo: images downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.mf.1.pz
:downloader: [0xa1427d0] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.mf.1.pz ]
:PackageInfo: Uncompressing .//osx_i386/Cobra.app/Contents/Resources/images/images.mf.1.pz to .//osx_i386/Cobra.app/Contents/Resources/images/images.mf
:PackageInfo: Unpacking .//osx_i386/Cobra.app/Contents/Resources/images/images.mf
:PackageInfo: panda3d downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/osx_i386/panda3d.cmu_1.8.osx_i386.xml
:downloader: [0xa142958] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/osx_i386/panda3d.cmu_1.8.osx_i386.xml ]

:PackageInfo: panda3d downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/osx_i386/panda3d.cmu_1.8.osx_i386.mf.1.pz
:downloader: [0xa142958] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/osx_i386/panda3d.cmu_1.8.osx_i386.mf.1.pz ]
:PackageInfo: Uncompressing .//osx_i386/Cobra.app/Contents/Resources/panda3d/cmu_1.8/panda3d.cmu_1.8.osx_i386.mf.1.pz to .//osx_i386/Cobra.app/Contents/Resources/panda3d/cmu_1.8/panda3d.cmu_1.8.osx_i386.mf
:PackageInfo: Unpacking .//osx_i386/Cobra.app/Contents/Resources/panda3d/cmu_1.8/panda3d.cmu_1.8.osx_i386.mf
:Installer: Creating .//osx_i386/Cobra 0.2.pkg...
:Installer: Creating .//linux_amd64/cobra_0.2_amd64.deb...
:PackageInfo: p3dembed downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/linux_amd64/p3dembed.linux_amd64.xml
:downloader: [0xa2cfeb8] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/linux_amd64/p3dembed.linux_amd64.xml ]
:PackageInfo: p3dembed downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/linux_amd64/p3dembed.linux_amd64.mf.1.pz
:downloader: [0xa2d1700] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/linux_amd64/p3dembed.linux_amd64.mf.1.pz ]
:PackageInfo: Uncompressing /tmp/cobraLFFwea/p3dembed/linux_amd64/p3dembed.linux_amd64.mf.1.pz to /tmp/cobraLFFwea/p3dembed/linux_amd64/p3dembed.linux_amd64.mf
:PackageInfo: Unpacking /tmp/cobraLFFwea/p3dembed/linux_amd64/p3dembed.linux_amd64.mf
:Standalone: Creating /tmp/cobralgZXTK/linux_amd64/usr/bin/cobra...
:HostInfo: Downloading contents file [ https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093292 ]

:downloader: [0xa2cfeb8] begin GET [ https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093292 ]
:HostInfo(warning): Successfully downloaded https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093292
:PackageInfo: images downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.xml
:downloader: [0x9fd6740] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.xml ]
:PackageInfo: images downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.mf.1.pz
:downloader: [0xa145460] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.mf.1.pz ]
:PackageInfo: Uncompressing /tmp/cobralgZXTK/linux_amd64/usr/lib/cobra/images/images.mf.1.pz to /tmp/cobralgZXTK/linux_amd64/usr/lib/cobra/images/images.mf
:PackageInfo: Unpacking /tmp/cobralgZXTK/linux_amd64/usr/lib/cobra/images/images.mf
:PackageInfo: panda3d downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/linux_amd64/panda3d.cmu_1.8.linux_amd64.xml
:downloader: [0xa154358] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/linux_amd64/panda3d.cmu_1.8.linux_amd64.xml ]
:PackageInfo: panda3d downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/linux_amd64/panda3d.cmu_1.8.linux_amd64.mf.1.pz
:downloader: [0xa154358] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/linux_amd64/panda3d.cmu_1.8.linux_amd64.mf.1.pz ]
:PackageInfo: Uncompressing /tmp/cobralgZXTK/linux_amd64/usr/lib/cobra/panda3d/cmu_1.8/panda3d.cmu_1.8.linux_amd64.mf.1.pz to /tmp/cobralgZXTK/linux_amd64/usr/lib/cobra/panda3d/cmu_1.8/panda3d.cmu_1.8.linux_amd64.mf
:PackageInfo: Unpacking /tmp/cobralgZXTK/linux_amd64/usr/lib/cobra/panda3d/cmu_1.8/panda3d.cmu_1.8.linux_amd64.mf
:Installer: Creating .//linux_amd64/cobra-0.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.gz...
:Installer: Creating .//osx_ppc/Cobra.app...
:PackageInfo: p3dembed downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/osx_ppc/p3dembed.osx_ppc.xml
:downloader: [0xa147100] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/osx_ppc/p3dembed.osx_ppc.xml ]
:PackageInfo: p3dembed downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/osx_ppc/p3dembed.osx_ppc.mf.1.pz
:downloader: [0xa1c7770] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/p3dembed/osx_ppc/p3dembed.osx_ppc.mf.1.pz ]
:PackageInfo: Uncompressing /tmp/cobraLFFwea/p3dembed/osx_ppc/p3dembed.osx_ppc.mf.1.pz to /tmp/cobraLFFwea/p3dembed/osx_ppc/p3dembed.osx_ppc.mf
:PackageInfo: Unpacking /tmp/cobraLFFwea/p3dembed/osx_ppc/p3dembed.osx_ppc.mf
:Standalone: Creating .//osx_ppc/Cobra.app/Contents/MacOS/cobra...
:PackageInfo: images downloading https://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.xml
:downloader: [0xa159be8] begin GET [ https://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.xml ]
:PackageInfo(warning): After downloading, images.xml incorrect
:HostInfo: Redownloading https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml
:HostInfo: Downloading contents file [ https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093456 ]

:downloader: [0xa042cd0] begin GET [ https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093456 ]
:HostInfo(warning): Successfully downloaded https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml?1405093456
:HostInfo: https://runtime.panda3d.org/contents.xml has changed.
:PackageInfo: images downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.xml
:downloader: [0xa150918] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.xml ]
:PackageInfo: images downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.mf.1.pz
:downloader: [0xa15a208] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/images/images.mf.1.pz ]
:PackageInfo: Uncompressing .//osx_ppc/Cobra.app/Contents/Resources/images/images.mf.1.pz to .//osx_ppc/Cobra.app/Contents/Resources/images/images.mf
:PackageInfo: Unpacking .//osx_ppc/Cobra.app/Contents/Resources/images/images.mf
:PackageInfo: panda3d downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/osx_ppc/panda3d.cmu_1.8.osx_ppc.xml
:downloader: [0xa14ecf0] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/osx_ppc/panda3d.cmu_1.8.osx_ppc.xml ]
:PackageInfo: panda3d downloading http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/osx_ppc/panda3d.cmu_1.8.osx_ppc.mf.1.pz
:downloader: [0xa14ecf0] begin GET [ http://runtime.panda3d.org/panda3d/cmu_1.8/osx_ppc/panda3d.cmu_1.8.osx_ppc.mf.1.pz ]
:PackageInfo: Uncompressing .//osx_ppc/Cobra.app/Contents/Resources/panda3d/cmu_1.8/panda3d.cmu_1.8.osx_ppc.mf.1.pz to .//osx_ppc/Cobra.app/Contents/Resources/panda3d/cmu_1.8/panda3d.cmu_1.8.osx_ppc.mf
:PackageInfo: Unpacking .//osx_ppc/Cobra.app/Contents/Resources/panda3d/cmu_1.8/panda3d.cmu_1.8.osx_ppc.mf
:Installer: Creating .//osx_ppc/Cobra 0.2.pkg...
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing more information, like the operating system version you're using, and the output of "which makensis" on the command-line?

Comment: Well, @rdb, I think there is a lot of redundant lines from log. I've read all of it and found only one line which contains word `"makensis"`. This line was posted first...

Comment: You should try to find the location of "makensis" on your system, and then add that to your PATH variable.  For instance, if makensis is located in `/my/directory/makensis`, you should run `export PATH=/my/directory:$PATH` before running pdeploy.

Comment: It seems to me that there is no makensis on my machine at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search on packages.ubuntu.com shows that the `makensis` utility can be found in the `nsis` package.  So, installing that with your package manager should make this error go away.

Comment: Oh, who would have thought that makensis is in the nsis package. I've just installed it via apt-tet and no magic with the PATH variable wasn't required. Thank you a lot)